# Problems with UITableViewDataSource - xCode Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift4

I am having a problem with a UITableViewDataSource. I will share my code below as I explain:

I start by creating the UITableViewDataSource:

```
//Create Vars
let cellId = "cellId1"
var selectedItems: [String?] = []

//Create Lazy Vars
lazy var ItemVC = ItemsViewController()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! MyCell

    print(selectedItems)

    return cell
}
```

Then, I set selectedItems in another ViewController:

```
var selectedItems: [String?] = []

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedItems = lists[indexPath.row].items
    ItemsDS.selectedItems = selectedItems
    ItemsVC.navigationItem.title = lists[indexPath.row].name
    navigationController?.pushViewController(ItemsVC, animated: true)
}
```

Here is my lists array referenced in the code above. By the way, the code above is a UITableViewController and which displays lists.name and what I want it to do is when one is pressed it goes to another UIViewController (from the data source above) and displays the items of the list:

```
    var lists: [List] = [
    List(name: "Veggies", items: ["Fruit Loops", "Pasta"]),
    List(name: "11/17/18", items: ["Eggs", "Green Beans", "Pirate Booty", "Bread", "Milk"]),
    List(name: "Fruits", items: ["Fruit Loops", "Oranges"]),
    List(name: "Red Foods", items: ["Apples", "Tomatoes", "Watermelon", "Cherries"]),
    List(name: "Grains", items: ["Bread Crumbs", "Pasta", "Rice", "Chicken Flavored Rice"])
]
```

Finally, I set the data source in another view controller:

```
    tableView.dataSource = ItemDS

    //Register TableView with Id: cellId
    tableView.register(MyCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ItemDS.cellId)
```

The problem is that selectedItems in my data source return []. However, in my view controller where I set selectedItems, it returns the right thing. Thanks!

Comment: did  didSelectRowAtIndexPath  call?

Comment: @AnkurLahiry Yes, in the second code excerpt. It is called in the view controller that, when an item is pressed, transitions to the view controller that has the data source problem. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: `itemVC` is an independent instance of that view controller that you have created. It is not the instance that is on screen.

Comment: @Paulw11... Not sure I understand. Sorry, I am new to this. Just to clarify for you, ListVC is the class that displays names of shopping lists. The didSelectRowAt indexPath and the lists array are in the ListVC. Then, when a list is selected from the ListVC, I push to the ViewController called ItemVC. ItemVC is also a UITableViewController whose data source comes from ItemDataSource, or ItemDS as referenced above. Also, when a list is selected from ListVC's tableView, I set a variable in ItemDS called selectedItem to equal the lists[indexPath.row].items. However, selectedItem in ItemDS is nil.

Comment: @Paulw11 All I want to do is have a UITableViewController that displays lists[indexPath.row].name (ListVC) and when a name is pressed on, then display its items in another ViewController (ItemVC), using a data source (ItemDS). If you have an easier way to do this, let me know. Thanks!